# Stateful Widget Menu in multiple stateful classes

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, widget, stateful

I have a question regarding stateful widget calls:
I created a floating-action-button menu in a stateful class, as the data may change at runtime.
Now, I want to access the fab menu in other stateful classes (and other screens).
But I'm not able to do so and could only do so in stateless classes.
Hope you can help me!! Thank you so much!

(I created the similar to: https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package or any other state management package to handle that.
or simply you can make a static menu and you'll be able to modify it from any Class (Screen)